# Laravel 5.3 and vue.js: associated queries and show the data

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I am using Laravel `5.3` and `vue.js`.

There are 3 tables,`users`、`articles`、`images`,
users and articles，one to many.
articles and images，one to one.(image doesn't become a field of the table articles temporarily)

controller:

```
public function articles()
{
    $user=\Auth::user();
    $articles = $user->articles()->with('images')->get();
    return $articles;
}
```

html:

```
        <div class="row" v-for="(index, item) in items">

            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @{{ item.title }}
            </div>

            <div class="col-xs-2">
                @{{ item.image }}
            </div>
        </div>
```

javascripts：

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Vue.config.debug = true;
    var vm = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: function(){
            return{
                items: []
            }
        },
        created() {
            var article=this;
           /* $.getJSON('/articles/image',function(data){
                console.log(data);
                article.items=data;
            });*/

            this.$http.get('/articles/image').then((response) => {
                console.log(response.body);
                article.items=response.body;
            }, (response) => {
                // error callback
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

I have 2 questions,the code is in javascripts:

1、When using `$.getJSON`,field `title` is ok,`image` can not be shown,how to show it?

2、When using `vue-resource`, both fields can not be shown,how to show them?

Comment: Why do you call it like so `@{{ item.image }}`. When you have one to many relation `images`. It should be an array, shouldn't it? Also, it would be nice if you can provide your json output with 2-3 items

Comment: When using vue-resource you should get the data with response.data, not response.body